# Installing eclipse plug-in built by Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I want to install eclipse plug-in that was build with help of Tycho. 
When I call `mvn clean install` Maven exits with SUCCESS, and in target directory there is .jar file.
I can't make Eclipse to work with this .jar, it says that file could not be found. 
Am I missing something here? How to use my tycho built plug-in? 
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.example</groupId>
<artifactId>com.my.example.ExampleProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
<repositories>  
    <repository>
        <id>eclipse-luna</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>macosx</os>
                        <ws>cocoa</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you have the plug-in already package as an eclipse plug-in ? or do you have the plug-in as source ?

Comment: @flafoux: I have both, I generate sources package with maven-source-plugin.

Comment: then if you have the eclipse plug-in you can install it in eclipse with `help > install new software > Add... > Local... or Archive...`